# How can I initialize the ListView used once with SmallImageList in VB.net?

Tags: image, listview, format, initialization, populate

I use one ListView and populate data to the ListView. When I use its SmallImageList, its format is shown in below.

[image]

The problem is that the format is not initialized. I would like to reset the ListView to the intial state such as New ListView like below.

[image]

I tried my best for the initialization with `lv.clear`, `lv.items.clear`, and everything I can.
Please, Help me to get rid of my headache!!!!